# Mocking one method with different values

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I still have some difficulties with Mockito. I want to have two test cases for two different object examples. So I want to simulate different method behaviour depending on argument value.

The problem is that when I run `test()` method, the returned value of `help` valiable is "b" and the assertion doesn't return true. If I comment the line marked as `(***)`, everything works fine.

As you can see I tried to use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`, but the result was the same.

```
public class TestItAll {
      TestClass test;

      HelpClass a ;
      HelpClass b;

      @Before
      public void init(){

          a = new HelpClass("a");
          b = new HelpClass("b");

          Mockito.when(test.getHelp(a)).thenReturn("a");
          /*Mockito.when(test.getHelp(a)).thenAnswer(
            new Answer< String>() {
                  public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                      return "a";
                  }
            });         */
          Mockito.when(test.getHelp(b)).thenReturn("b");//(***)

          /*Mockito.when(test.getHelp(b)).thenAnswer(
            new Answer< String>() {
                  public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                      return "b";
                  }
            });         */
      }


      @Test
      public void testA(){
          String help= test.getHelp(a);
          Assert.assertEquals(help, "a");
      }

      /*@Test
      public void testB(){
          String help= test.getHelp(b);
          Assert.assertEquals(help, "b");
      }*/
}
```

Please, don't ask me why I'm mocking a test object. It's just a model example of a more complicated situation.

Comment: Code for `HelpClass` could be helpful in order to get an answer. (You might also want to remove not required part, i.e. commented parts). As a side note, it's not clear what you are trying to test here (mockito behavior maybe?)

Comment: `getHelp` isn't final, is it? If it is, then the Mockito code won't be called at all.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I assume that your declaration `TestClass test;` is in fact `TestClass test = mock(TestClass.class);`, otherwise the `@Before` method throws `NullPointerException`.

When using `when(test.getHelp(a))` mockito will use `a`'s `equals` method to check whether the parameter matched. If e.g. `equals` method always returns `true`, it won't be able to differ `a` from `b`. I have run your code with overriding `equals` method (i.e. `HelpClass` objects are equal only if they are the same instance) and both tests have passed.

You may want to use argument matcher - `when(test.getHelp(argThat(sameInstance(a))))` to not rely on your `equals` method. If you need something more complex than `sameInstance`, I would recommend `sameBeanAs` matcher from [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest).